Matched Geometry Effect animation bug
I have a basic view that tries to animate a single image to a tab view of images. I am encountering some animation issues using the code below. Also in the bottom scroll view, the images are view aligned on the leading edge, how can I view align them in the center without making each image the full width of the screen?

Clicking on the first image animates fine (could be smoother)
Clicking on the second image presents a paging scroll view that is bugged (half of image1/image2 are shown)
Clicking on the third image works, but the first image flickers during animation

Copy paste-able working code, (you need king fisher, otherwise use asyncimage):
import SwiftUI
import Kingfisher

struct TopPostMediaView: View {
    @State var isExpanded: Bool = false
    @Namespace var animation
    @State var detailScrollPosition: UUID? = nil
    @State var animMid = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader {
            let size = $0.size
            ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                HStack(spacing: 10) {
                    ForEach(mynewtemp) { pic in
                        LazyHStack {
                            let mid = pic.photo + pic.id.uuidString
                            
                            if !isExpanded || animMid != mid {
                                KFImage(URL(string: pic.photo))
                                    .resizable()
                                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                                    .frame(maxWidth: size.width)
                                    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10))
                                    .contentShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10))
                                    .matchedGeometryEffect(id: mid, in: animation)
                                    .onTapGesture {
                                        //move to the image
                                        detailScrollPosition = pic.id
                                        //sub view id to animate up
                                        animMid = mid
                                        //present top view
                                        withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.15)){
                                            isExpanded = true
                                        }
                                    }
                            } else {
                                KFImage(URL(string: pic.photo))
                                    .resizable()
                                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                                    .frame(maxWidth: size.width)
                                    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10))
                                    .contentShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10))
                                    .opacity(0.0)
                            }
                        }
                        .frame(maxWidth: size.width).frame(height: size.height)
                        .contentShape(.rect)
                    }
                }.scrollTargetLayout()
            }
            .scrollPosition(id: $detailScrollPosition, anchor: .center)
            .scrollIndicators(.hidden)
            .scrollTargetBehavior(.viewAligned)
            .scrollClipDisabled()
        }
        .frame(height: 250)
        .overlay {
            if isExpanded {
                ZStack {
                    Color.black.frame(height: viewHeight() + 30.0).clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 40))
                    ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                        LazyHStack(spacing: 0) {
                            ForEach(mynewtemp) { pic in
                                KFImage(URL(string: pic.photo))
                                    .resizable()
                                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                    .containerRelativeFrame(.horizontal)
                                    .clipped()
                            }
                        }.scrollTargetLayout()
                    }
                    .matchedGeometryEffect(id: animMid, in: animation)
                    .scrollPosition(id: $detailScrollPosition)
                    .scrollTargetBehavior(.paging)
                    .scrollIndicators(.hidden)
                    .overlay(alignment: .topLeading) {
                        Button("", systemImage: "xmark.circle.fill") {
                            withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.15)){
                                isExpanded = false
                            }
                        }
                        .foregroundStyle(.white.opacity(0.8), .white.opacity(0.15))
                        .padding(.top, 100).padding(.leading)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// IGNORE

#Preview {
    TopPostMediaView()
}

let mynewtemp: [tempStruct] = [tempStruct(id: UUID(), photo: "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRmCy16nhIbV3pI1qLYHMJKwbH2458oiC9EmA&s"), tempStruct(id: UUID(), photo: "https://th.bing.com/th/id/OIG2.9O4YqGf98tiYzjKDvg7L"), tempStruct(id: UUID(), photo: "https://th.bing.com/th/id/OIG2.9O4YqGf98tiYzjKDvg7L")]

struct tempStruct: Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id: UUID
    var photo: String
}

func viewHeight() -> CGFloat {
    let scenes = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes
    let windowScene = scenes.first as? UIWindowScene
    let window = windowScene?.windows.first
    return window?.screen.bounds.height ?? 0
}


If you can rule out Kingfisher as a potential culprit, please reduce your example by removing it and replacing it with some static images, preferable some SF symbols.

You probably get a better visual effect, if you don't remove the tapped image in the first list (you may give it a different color or different opacity), and also animate the scroll position detailScrollPosition in the first list (within withAnimation). IMHO, you should also rethink how you calculate the frames which is tricky when you are using ZStack and GeometryReader and magical constants.

My guess is that scrollTargetBehavior(.viewAligned) always aligns to the leading edge of the view, because there is no way to specify an anchor. The anchor supplied to scrollPosition is unrelated. As a workaround, you could implement your own ScrollTargetBehavior, but it will be difficult if the images can all have different widths.

@CouchDeveloper I tried it with Async Image and I got the same issue, I don't think it's a King fisher issue. Also you can't have 2 views with the same matched geo id, you have to hide one, when showing the other, otherwise errors get printed. Adding an animation to detailScrollPosition doesn't do anything.

Ahmed, please note that you have indeed two different views (KFImage ) in the first list: the if !isExpanded || animMid != mid {#1} else {#2}.  Fixing this, however, does not solve your UI issues, since there are errors due to other frames and layout issues.

The following code animates an image from a bottom level view (in a scrollview, or not) to an overlaying tabview. You can pick between the overlaying tabview, there is galleryView() which is a horizontal pager, and mediaView() which is a vertical pager. The galleryView() also supports zoom gestures. The overlay views can also be swiped to close.
struct TopPostMediaView: View {
    @State var offset: CGSize = .zero
    @State var scale: CGFloat = 1
    @State var lastScale: CGFloat = 1
    
    @State var isExpanded: Bool = false
    @Namespace var animation
    @State var detailScrollPosition: UUID? = nil
    @State var animMid = ""

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10) {
                GeometryReader {
                    let size = $0.size
                    ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                        HStack(spacing: 10) {
                            ForEach(mynewtemp) { pic in
                                LazyHStack {
                                    let mid = pic.photo + pic.id.uuidString
                                    
                                    if !isExpanded || animMid != mid {
                                        KFImage(URL(string: pic.photo))
                                            .resizable()
                                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                                            .frame(maxWidth: size.width)
                                            .overlay(content: {
                                                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10).stroke(Color.gray.opacity(0.4), lineWidth: 1.0)
                                            })
                                            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10))
                                            .contentShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10))
                                            .frame(height: 250)
                                            .matchedGeometryEffect(id: mid, in: animation)
                                            .onTapGesture {
                                                withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.15)){
                                                    detailScrollPosition = pic.id
                                                }
                                                animMid = mid
                                                withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.15)){
                                                    isExpanded = true
                                                }
                                            }
                                    } else {
                                        KFImage(URL(string: pic.photo))
                                            .resizable()
                                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                                            .frame(maxWidth: size.width)
                                            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10))
                                            .contentShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10))
                                            .opacity(0.0)
                                    }
                                }
                                .frame(maxWidth: size.width)
                                .frame(height: size.height)
                                .contentShape(.rect)
                            }
                        }
                        .scrollTargetLayout()
                    }
                    .scrollIndicators(.hidden)
                    .scrollTargetBehavior(.viewAligned)
                    .scrollClipDisabled()
                }.frame(height: 250)
            }
        }
        .overlay {
            if isExpanded {
                mediaView()
            }
        }
    }
    @ViewBuilder
    func mediaView() -> some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.black.frame(height: widthOrHeight(width: false) + 30.0)
                .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 40))
            ScrollView {
                LazyVStack(spacing: 0) {
                    ForEach(mynewtemp) { pic in
                        KFImage(URL(string: pic.photo))
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                            .containerRelativeFrame(.vertical)
                            .clipped()
                    }
                }.scrollTargetLayout()
            }
            .matchedGeometryEffect(id: animMid, in: animation)
            .scrollPosition(id: $detailScrollPosition)
            .scrollTargetBehavior(.paging)
            .scrollIndicators(.hidden)
            .overlay(alignment: .topLeading) {
                Button("", systemImage: "xmark.circle.fill") {
                    withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.15)){
                        isExpanded = false
                    }
                }
                .foregroundStyle(.white.opacity(0.8), .white.opacity(0.15))
                .padding(.top, 100).padding(.leading)
            }
        }
        .offset(x: offset.width, y: offset.height)
        .gesture (
            DragGesture()
                .onChanged { value in
                    if value.translation.height >= 0 || offset != .zero {
                        offset = value.translation
                    }
                }
                .onEnded({ value in
                    withAnimation {
                        offset = .zero
                    }
                    if value.translation.height > 100 {
                        withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.15)){
                            isExpanded = false
                        }
                    }
                })
        )
    }
    @ViewBuilder
    func galleryView() -> some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.black.frame(height: widthOrHeight(width: false) + 30.0)
                .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 40))
            GeometryReader { geo in
                TabView(selection: $detailScrollPosition) {
                    ForEach(mynewtemp) { pic in
                        KFImage(URL(string: pic.photo))
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                            .frame(width: widthOrHeight(width: true))
                            .containerRelativeFrame(.horizontal)
                            .clipShape(Rectangle())
                            .contentShape(Rectangle())
                            .scaleEffect(scale)
                            .gesture(makeMagnificationGesture(size: geo.size))
                            .tag(pic.id)
                    }
                }
                .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .never))
                .matchedGeometryEffect(id: animMid, in: animation)
                .overlay(alignment: .topLeading) {
                    Button("", systemImage: "xmark.circle.fill") {
                        withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.15)){
                            isExpanded = false
                        }
                    }
                    .foregroundStyle(.white.opacity(0.8), .white.opacity(0.15)).font(.title)
                    .padding(.top, 100).padding(.leading)
                }
            }
        }
        .offset(x: offset.width, y: offset.height)
        .gesture (
            DragGesture()
                .onChanged { value in
                    if value.translation.height >= 0 || offset != .zero {
                        offset = value.translation
                    }
                }
                .onEnded({ value in
                    withAnimation {
                        offset = .zero
                    }
                    if value.translation.height > 100 {
                        withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.15)){
                            isExpanded = false
                        }
                    }
                })
        )
    }
    private func makeMagnificationGesture(size: CGSize) -> some Gesture {
        MagnificationGesture()
            .onChanged { value in
                let delta = value / lastScale
                lastScale = value

                if abs(1 - delta) > 0.01 {
                    scale *= delta
                }
            }
            .onEnded { _ in
                lastScale = 1
                withAnimation {
                    scale = 1
                }
            }
    }
}

//#Preview {
//    TopPostMediaView()
//}

let mynewtemp: [tempStruct] = [tempStruct(id: UUID(), photo: "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRmCy16nhIbV3pI1qLYHMJKwbH2458oiC9EmA&s"), tempStruct(id: UUID(), photo: "https://th.bing.com/th/id/OIG2.9O4YqGf98tiYzjKDvg7L"), tempStruct(id: UUID(), photo: "https://th.bing.com/th/id/OIG2.9O4YqGf98tiYzjKDvg7L")]

struct tempStruct: Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id: UUID
    var photo: String
}

func widthOrHeight(width: Bool) -> CGFloat {
    let scenes = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes
    let windowScene = scenes.first as? UIWindowScene
    let window = windowScene?.windows.first
    
    if width {
        return window?.screen.bounds.width ?? 0
    } else {
        return window?.screen.bounds.height ?? 0
    }
}

